# Keycloak term and condition as a seperate page

Tags: registration, keycloak

When configured in Authentication, newly registered user can see the `Term and Condition` page of Keycloak for the first time. After that, they cannot see it anymore

I would like to have a simple link to that page for anyone to view the content. The best would be an static url pointing to a template.

Is it achievable with Keycloak?

Comment: Is it possible to link the keycloak's one statically?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by creating your own [keycloak themes](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes). You can for example create a static url in the login template (login.ftl) that points to terms and condition template (terms.ftl).

You can also create a terms.html and place it in the resource folder inside the login folder. Then link to that html file inside the login.ftl with:

`<a href="${url.resourcesPath}/terms.html"> terms and conditions</a>`

Doing the second example forces you to maintain the terms and conditions in two files.

Comment: That, as far as I know, is not possible. The terms.ftl reside in the login theme as the login.ftl. I think Keycloak only allow link to other 5 predefined theme types as their default

Comment: hmm, if that is the case i added a second solution which i have tested and know works.